# Debugging Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, debugging, webpack

So I'm new to Typescript, and recently converted a React project to TS to suss the benefits. I managed to convert and compile it all, and I can step through it, in the same way, I stepped through the JS code, however, I've hit a snag.

I usually like to pause at a given line and play around with code snippets in the watch window to see what might be happening. This particular issue was a use of instanceOf of a custom type I had defined, which is obviously not valid JS, as JS doesn't have types. But it meant I couldn't evaluate the highlighted code in the watch window because it doesn't understand TS. If I want to move to TS, do I lose this ability due to the conversion to JS? Or is there a way around it?

I'm using React with Webpack, debugging in Chrome via Visual Studio Code.

Comment: you don't have the ability to use Typescript in the console, but you can still use JS to evaluate things in the console

Comment: JS has types. Try `class A {}; let x = new A(); console.log(x instanceof A)`. Or did you mean for interfaces (or actual TS types with the `type` keyword)?

Comment: I'm comparing it with classes I've exported. But the console doesn't know about them.

Comment: Insert `debugger;` statements into your TypeScript. It should pause execution if you have the inspection window open. If you compile it with source maps enabled, your browser should give you the option to show you the TypeScript in the debugger instead of the JavaScript.